# Find search var in 2 related models but limited to array of ids

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-query-builder

I'm using a search field to find a possible `tag.name` within orders that are being limited by a `->whereIn('id', $allowed_ids)` but at the same time use the same search field to find a possible `name` from a client that placed these orders.

Due to the underlying permission system clientss are viewable by all inside a specific team and orders are automated who is allowed to see them with a sort of referral system (basically a table saying who brought them in and who gets the "commission" on an order).

The normal data structure looks like this:

```
order          order
  ├ client1      ├ client1
  ├ client3      ├ client2
```

But should now I'm trying to recreate the structure to look like this:

```
client1        client2
  ├ order        ├ order
  ├ order        ├ order
```

So because of this (and performance) I need to first find all unique client_id's from the orders that are visible to the current logged in user to then get then link the orders to the client and return them.

But the search has been a little tricky. I can't use `andWhere` because it's possible the user is not looking for a tag but I can't use `orWhere` because I need it to be limited to the ids.

If this where to be sql I would just slap a `select * from () x where tags.name like search ... etc` but I can't seem to make that work in eloquent so I put that pursuit on hold for the time being.

```
$callback = function (Builder $query) use ($referral_ids) {
    $query->whereIn('referrals.id', $referral_ids);
};

$orders = Order::select('client_id')
    ->whereHas('referrals', $callback);

if ($request->has('search')) {
    $searches = explode(' ', $request->search);
    $orders 
        ->leftJoin('order_tag', 'order.id', 'order_tag.order_id')
        ->leftJoin('tags', 'order_tag.tag_id', 'tags.id')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($searches) {
            foreach ($searches as $search) {
                $query = $query->orWhere('tags.name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            }
        });
}

$orders = $orders->get();
```

Second part is getting the clients from the orders

```
$clients = Client::selectRaw('client.*, (select max(o.updated_at) from orders o where o.client_id = client.id) as last_updated_at')
    ->whereIn(
        'client.id',
        $orders->pluck('client_id')
    );


if ($request->has('search')) {
    $searches = explode(' ', $request->search);
    $clients->orWhere(function ($query) use ($searches) {
        foreach ($searches as $search) {
            $query
                ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        }
    });
}

$clients->orderBy('last_updated_at', 'DESC');
$clients = $clients->paginate($request->per_page);
```

Then everything gets paginated and according to the current active page orders get bound to the clients that are being showed.

The idea is that if someone where to type "john car" in the search field the result should be everyone with a name `john` or `car` and/or everyone that has an order with tags `john` or `car` but still limited to the original limiting ids.

Optionally if it were possible (although I highly doubt it) to make clients that have the name "john" and a tag named "car" to be placed above "john" without any reference to "car" or clients with another name than "john" but that do have a car.